# What real-life fruit do the Berry names reference in Pokemon?

Tags: terminology, pokemon-series

I have been making a lot of curry in *Pokémon Sword/Shield*, and the names of some of these berries don't make any sense. I mean, I know Pecha Berries are meant to be peaches, and Pinap Berries are referring to pineapples, but what's a Leppa berry supposed to be?

Here's all the Berries - ones with question marks I'm not sure of. Can anyone help me figure out what these berries are supposed to be referencing?

- Aguav → Guava
- Apicot → Apricot
- Aspear → ?
- Babiri → ?
- Belue → Blueberry?
- Bluk → ?
- Chari → ?
- Cheri → Cherry
- Chesto → Chestnut?
- Chilan → ?
- Chople → ?
- Coba → ?
- Colbur → ?
- Cornn → Corn
- Custap → ?
- Drash → Radish? (I don't have visuals but it looks like a radish)
- Durin → Durian
- Eggant → Eggplant
- Enigma → Enigma (Who knew?)
- Figy → Fig
- Ganlon → ?
- Ginema → ?
- Grepa → Grape
- Haban → ?
- Hondew → Honeydew
- Jacoba → ?
- Kasib → ?
- Kebia → ?
- Kee → ?
- Kelpsy → ?
- Kuo → ?
- Lansat → ?
- Lapapa → ?
- Leppa → ?
- Liechi → ?
- Lum → ?
- Mago → Mango
- Magost → ?
- Maranga → ?
- Micle → Miracle?
- Nanab → Banana
- Niniku → ?
- Nomel → Normal?
- Nutpea → Both a Nut and a Pea?
- Occa → ?
- Oran → Ordinary?
- Pamtre → Palm tree?
- Passho → Pistachio?
- Payapa → Papaya
- Pecha → Peach
- Persim → Parsnip?
- Petaya → ?
- Pinap → Pineapple
- Pomeg → ?
- Pumkin → Pumpkin
- Qualot → ?
- Rabuta → Rutabaga?
- Rawst → Roast?
- Razz → Raspberry
- Rindo → ?
- Roseli → Rose
- Rowap → ?
- Salac → ?
- Shuca → ?
- Sitrus → Citrus
- Spelon → ?
- Starf → ?
- Strib → ?
- Tamato → Tomato
- Tanga → ?
- Topo → ?
- Touga → ?
- Wacan → ?
- Watmel → Watermelon
- Wepear → Pear?
- Wiki → ?
- Yache → ?
- Yago → ?

Comment: Bulbapedia has this information, as pulled from different names/translations used in-game around the world. The real life fruit/veg reference is on each individual Berry page. (go to the #Names section, eg: https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Aspear_Berry#Names). I don't see how that is "speculation on the Developer's intent" as per the current close reason.

Comment: Yeah, really confused why this is closed - seems a straightforward question to me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yago berry is a bitter melon. Kuo berry is Okra, etc. There are some berries which have no English name, in that case they are translations. To get the full list, check [Bulbapedia's page on Berries](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Berry). From there, you can check the individual articles for each Berry you don't know, then check the Origin/design section.

For example:

- Aspear berries are based on pears
  [image: Aspear Origin - Bulbapedia]
- Leppa berries are based on apples (hence the anagram)
  [image: Leppa Origin - Bulbapedia]

The whole list:

| Berry | Based on |
| --- | --- |
| Cheri Berry | Cherry |
| Chesto Berry | Chestnut |
| Pecha Berry | Peach |
| Rawst Berry | Strawberry |
| Aspear Berry | Asian pear |
| Leppa Berry | Apple |
| Oran Berry | Orange |
| Persim Berry | Persimmon |
| Lum Berry | Plum |
| Sitrus Berry | Citrus |
| Figy Berry | Fig |
| Wiki Berry | Kiwi |
| Mago Berry | Mango |
| Aguav Berry | Guava |
| Iapapa Berry | Papaya |
| Razz Berry | Raspberry |
| Bluk Berry | Blackberry |
| Nanab Berry | Banana |
| Wepear Berry | Western Pear |
| Pinap Berry | Pineapple |
| Pomeg Berry | Pomegranate |
| Kelpsy Berry | Kelp |
| Qualot Berry | Loquat |
| Hondew Berry | Honeydew |
| Grepa Berry | Grape |
| Tamato Berry | Tomato |
| Cornn Berry | Corn |
| Magost Berry | Mangosteen |
| Rabuta Berry | Rambutan |
| Nomel Berry | Lemon |
| Spelon Berry | Spiked Melon |
| Pamtre Berry | Palm tree |
| Watmel Berry | Watermelon |
| Durin Berry | Durian |
| Belue Berry | Blueberry |
| Occa Berry | Cocao |
| Passho Berry | Passionfruit |
| Wacan Berry | Wax Candle |
| Rindo Berry | Tamarind |
| Yache Berry | Cherimoya |
| Chople Berry | Chipotle |
| Kebia Berry | Akebia |
| Shuca Berry | Cashew nut |
| Coba Berry | Babaco |
| Payapa Berry | Papaya |
| Tanga Berry | Pitanga |
| Charti Berry | Artichoke |
| Kasib Berry | Cassava |
| Haban Berry | Terihabanjirō. |
| Colbur Berry | Cocklebur |
| Babiri Berry | Biriba |
| Chilan Berry | Chinese lantern |
| Liechi Berry | Lychee |
| Ganlon Berry | Longan |
| Salac Berry | Salak |
| Petaya Berry | Pitaya |
| Apicot Berry | Apricot |
| Lansat Berry | Langsat |
| Starf Berry | Star fruit |
| Enigma Berry | Enigma |
| Micle Berry | Miracle fruit |
| Custap Berry | Custard Apple |
| Jaboca Berry | Jabuticaba |
| Rowap Berry | Water Apple |

Comment: Excellent work getting the whole list together! +1

Comment: Oh my god, it all makes sense now! Im gonna have to look up what a "Wax Candle" is when it comes to fruit tho, lol. Thats a new one!

Answer (score 0):

Also, some new berries were added in gen 6 and there were also berries you could only get from e-reader events:

Roseli - Roselle
Kee - Ackee
Maranga - Marang
Pumkin- Pumpkin
Drash - Radish
Eggant - Eggplant
Strib - String (as a reference to *edamame* or "string beans")
Nutpea - Peanut
Ginema - Tamanegi (Japanese for *onion*)
Kuo - okura (Japanese for *okra*)
Yago - Gooyaa (Japanese for *bitter melon*)
Touga - Togarashi (Japanese for *chili pepper*)
Niniku - Ninniku (Japanese for *garlic*)
Topo - Potato

I don't speak Japanese so I hope I spelled everything right.